# Simplify the code in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback, rails-models

I have 3 models and polymorphic relationships.
Post:

```
#models/post.rb

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_create :create_vote

   has_one :vote, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :votable

   protected
     def create_vote
        self.vote = Vote.create(:score => 0)
     end
end
```

Comment:

```
#models/comment.rb

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :create_vote

  has_one :vote, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :votable

  protected
    def create_vote
      self.vote = Vote.create(:score => 0)
    end
end
```

Vote (polymorphic)

```
#models/vote.rb
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

As you can see I have the same callbacks. How does it easier? If i make a module with callback this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define a module containing the same repeatable methods, but you would also have to define all the ActiveRecord macros when that module is included.

It might look something like this:

```
module VoteContainer
  def self.included(base)
    base.module_eval {
      after_create :create_vote
      has_one :vote, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :votable
    }
  end

  protected
  def create_vote
    self.vote = Vote.create(:score => 0)
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include VoteContainer
end
```